# Is it possible to know whether php://input contains data before starting reading it?

Tags: php, http

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), `php://input` does not always contain the HTTP request body.

I have some code that always opens the stream when the script starts, to make it available to the user application:

```php
$stream = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
```

If the user application tries to read from an empty stream, when `Content-Length > 0`, I want my library to throw an exception:

> The request body is not available.

My problem is that:

- If the stream is empty, `feof()` returns `false` while `fread()` has not been called;
- I can't `fread()` 1 byte then `fseek()`, as this stream does not support seeking;
- I can't open another `php://input` and try to read from it beforehand, as we can't rely on this stream to be available more than once;
- I don't want to blindly copy `php://input` to `php://temp` before giving the hand to the user application, for performance reasons.

Consequently, **is it possible to tell whether `php://input` contains data right after `fopen()`, but before any `fread()`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to create a class representing the request body, and reading from this class instead of `php://input` directly:

```php
class RequestBody
{
    protected $firstByte;

    protected $isEmpty;

    public function __construct($stream)
    {
        $this->firstByte = fread($stream, 1);
        $this->isEmpty = ($this->firstByte === '');

        // ...
    }

    public function isEmpty()
    {
        return $this->isEmpty;
    }

    public function read($length)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

$body = new RequestBody(fopen('php://input', 'rb'));
```

The class constructor reads the first byte of the stream, storing it for later use, and knowing instantly whether the stream is empty.

`read()` hides this complexity, by returning the first byte + `$length - 1` bytes the first time it's called.

Answer (score 0):

> "A stream opened with php://input can only be read once; the stream does not support seek operations."

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

To me this suggests that it's an old-fashioned read-only stream. You can't seek and test whether it's the end of a file or the length.